# Custom plugin is not shown in Users & Permissions plugin settings

Tags: strapi

I am trying to create my own custom plugin in Strapi. I have created one through the CLI (with the generate command) and after registering my plugin, it shows up in the navigation. However, I want to limit the access of the API endpoints. For this, I tried to change the settings in the *Users & Permissions* plugin but my custom plugin does not show up there.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to register the plugin anywhere specifically for the *Users & Permissions* plugin?

What I did so far:

- Registered the custom plugin in the config/plugin.ts
- create custom API logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question!

You need to open a custom route in user-permission, let me guide you

1. create a file of your name at user-psermissions/controllers/example.js
2. paste this below code and edit it as per requirement

   ```
    module.exports = plugin => {
    plugin.controllers.user.example = async ctx => {
     // ... codes
    };

   plugin.routes['content-api'].routes.push({
    method: 'PUT',
    path: '/user/example',
    handler: 'user.example',
    config: {
      prefix: '',
      policies: [],
     },
    });

    return plugin;
    };
   ```

Comment: Hey mainak! Thanks for the response. It works now but it shows up directly under the users-permissions section when I click the "public" in the roles. Is there a way to register it there as their own plugin section? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you brief about "their own plugin"

Answer (score 0):

User permissions are registered for api routes only. It’s not going to display permissions unless you add routes…